# How to read at once multiple lines from input and store each line a in list in Python to modify it?

Tags: arrays, input

I have tried doing something like this:

```
import sys
msg = sys.stdin.read()
```

but have no idea how to store each line of input in an array..I want to do it to print the modified message in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys

input_array = []

for line in sys.stdin:
  if 'Exit' == line.rstrip():
    break
  input_array.append(line)
```

If you really want to read everything in one call then you would need to do what you're doing, but then split msg by the line ending.

```py
import sys
import os

msg = sys.stdin.read()
msg_array = msg.split(os.linesep)
```